# Linux Ubuntu disk usage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, performance, hard-drive

Currently, I have a streaming dedicated server, below you will be able to see server details:

**HDD**: 12TB HDD
**RAM**: 64GB
**Processor**: Intel® Core™ i7-6700 Quad-Core Skylake Hyper-Threading
**Network speed**: 10GBPS unmtered
**OS**: Ubuntu 16.04

Also, I'm using nginx:

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 3;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 2000;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 25;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:10m;
        limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=3r/s;
        limit_rate_after 3m;
        limit_rate 2m;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; 
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        access_log off;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";


        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

But, when my dedicated server reach **~1500 simultaneous** connections, every person watching a video get video spike/lags.

How can I solve this issue?

Here is my I/O Usage:

```
 PID  PRIO  USER        DISK READ  DISK WRITE SWAPIN IO> COMMAND

 7855 be/4 www-data     30.30 G     92.00 K  0.00 % 86.06 % nginx: worker process
 7853 be/4 www-data     33.22 G     76.00 K  0.00 % 85.12 % nginx: worker process
 7852 be/4 www-data     35.39 G     44.00 K  0.00 % 84.01 % nginx: worker process
  335 be/3 root          0.00 B    684.00 K  0.00 % 15.13 % [jbd2/dm-0-8]
  378 be/3 root         19.93 M      6.13 M  0.00 %  2.23 % systemd-journald
 7811 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.57 % [kworker/u16:0-ixgbe]
  674 be/0 root        340.00 K      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.44 % [loop1]
 7812 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.29 % [kworker/u16:2-events_unbound]
 5471 be/4 root          0.00 B     24.00 K  0.00 %  0.14 % [kworker/3:3-events_long]
 5550 be/4 root          0.00 B     24.00 K  0.00 %  0.13 % [kworker/5:3-events_long]
 5513 be/4 root          0.00 B     24.00 K  0.00 %  0.12 % [kworker/0:1-events_long]
   67 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.11 % [kcompactd0]
 7061 be/4 root          4.00 K      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.07 % [kworker/u16:3-events_unbound]
  866 be/4 syslog        0.00 B    128.00 K  0.00 %  0.04 % rsyslogd -n
 7937 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.06 % [kworker/u16:1-events_unbound]
  940 be/4 root         26.00 K      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.02 % snapd
 5569 be/0 root          0.00 B     12.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % atop -R -w /var/log/atop/atop_20190413 600
 8059 be/4 root          0.00 B      4.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % sshd: root [priv]
```

As I can see, the problem is related to **I/O usage**, how can I reduce this usage and boost up my server performance?

Thank you

Comment: Get faster storage.

Comment: You have insufficient information to prove anything. Please edit your question to add network utilization (`iftop` or `nload`) CPU utilization (`vmstat 5`) and memory utilization (`cat /proc/meminfo`).  Ideally, try something like https://my-netdata.io/  and look at the alerts and graphs it generates.

Answer (score 0):

With about output, yeah I/O is the bottleneck, for any streaming applications you need better disk throughput, please use SSD with proper block size based on type/size of file you are going to serve. I would suggest to do disk benchmarking of your disk for that you can use third party too or **dd** command in linux or some other tools too. Best of luck.
Hope it will help.